# Помогите разобраться как работает готовый код построения дерева из строки с использованием ссылок?

Tags: php, дерево

На просторах интернета нашёл код позволяющий без применения рекурсии создавать "дерево" в виде массива из строки, чуть поменял под свои нужды и оно хорошо работает и как мне надо. Но! Никак не могу понять как оно работает "вардампы" и внимательный обзор то что есть [ссылки в php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.whatdo.php) мало что дали, я там понял что ссылки в php имеют похожую сущность что и в си, но тогда тем более не понятно. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться чтобы я в будущем мог самостоятельно оперировать подобными изящными конструкциями.

```
    function buildTreeArray($items)
{
    $resultData = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($items); $i++) {
        $item = $items[$i];
        $str = $item;
        $ref =& $resultData;
        foreach (explode('.', $str) as $v) {
            if(!isset($ref[$v])) {
                $ref[$v] = array();
            }
            $ref =& $ref[$v];
        }
     }
    return $resultData;
}
```

Comment: поясните, какие тут входные данные (формат), и какой результат вообще ожидается? массив строк,  где каждый элемент это путь от корня к листу записанный через точку что ли?

Comment: Да, ниже в ответе описано подробно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный алгоритм строит "дерево" с использованием массивов. Входные данные это массив строк. Каждый элемент строки это путь от корня до листа. Например,

```
$data = ["1.2.3.10", "1.2.4.9", "1.5.15"];
```

дает нам такое дерево:

```
1
|--2
|  |--3
|  |  |--10
|  |--4
|     |--9
|--5
   |--15
```

Надо понимать, что дерево это многоуровневый ассоциативный массив. Ключи это значения узлов. То есть результирующий массив будет иметь вид:

```
[ 
  1 => [ 
    2 => [ 
      3 => [... ],
      4 => [ ...],
    ],
    5 => [...] 
  ]
]
```

С таким же успехом, ключами могут быть и не числа, а строки, для данного алгоритма это не важно.

Для большей наглядности алгоритмы и кода функции, давайте немного перепишем его.

```
function buildTree2($items){
    $result = [];                                 // верхний уровень дерева


    foreach($items as $path){                     // перебор всех путей в исходных данных
        $ref = &$result;                          // для каждого пути, обзор дерева с верхнего уровня

        foreach(explode(".", $path) as $level){   // узлы для пути
            if(!array_key_exists($level, $ref)){  // есть ли узел на данном уровне?
                $ref[$level] = [];                // нет? - создаем его
            }
            $ref = &$ref[$level];                 // передвинулись на этот уровень
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

В общем говоря, каждую итерацию мы рассматриваем один путь. делим его на части, и продвигаемся вглубь. передвигая указатель (ссылку) текущего уровня, следуя по этому пути. Каждый раз начинаем мы со ссылки на верхний уровень "дерева".

Для этого алгоритма, конечно, важно что бы исходные данные представляли корректное дерево, и каждый элемент исходных данных всегда должен содержать полный путь от корня до листа. Это не какой то универсальный алгоритм, а простое решение частной задачи.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ, но мне не понятны тут именно 2 строки с ссылками: 
$ref = &$result; и 
$ref = &$ref[$level];
Если бы это не массив был бы то по сути это переменная ссылается одну на другую, а тут я не совсем понимаю как это работает.

Comment: @pdragon какая разница на что ссылаться, на обычную переменную, или на массив? массив это тоже переменная. Первая ссылка тут - по сути для инициализации. указывает на самый первый уровень результирующего массива. Далее мы по ссылкам переходим по ключам вложенных массивов в пути.